# how /etc/grub.d/41_custom is supposed to work?

Tags: grub2, bugs

I am asking, because fragment of file /boot/grub/grub.cfg looks like

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
    source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
    source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

I don't understood, how this should work, because there is no "source" command in grub2 - see

http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html

source if the command of /bin/sh shell.

I think, that this fragment should include ${config_directory}/custom.cfg

during the building of /boot/grub/grub.cfg (with grub-mkconfig):

```
[user@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/grub.d/41_custom 
#!/bin/sh
cat <<EOF
if [ -f  \${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
    source \${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "\${config_directory}" -a -f  \$prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
    source \$prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
EOF
```

but it doesn't!

it just inserts the text with the "source" command...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the description of mapping from *command* to modulename.mod

http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2010/06/grub2-modules.html?output=pdf

```
grep -E "^source" /boot/grub/i386-pc/command.lst
source: configfile

grep -E "^\.:" /boot/grub/i386-pc/command.lst
.: configfile
```

here is the code of function:

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/grub-core/commands/configfile.c#n61

So, "source" is just an undocumented command of grub2

Answer (score 1):

The manual for Grub 2.02 on the gnu.org website gives documentation for the "source" command at 16.3.71 in the "Command-line and Menu entry commands" section. So by 25th April 2017 - the date of the current version of the Grub Manual - the source command was documented and I now find it being used in the file /etc/grub.d/41_custom in the current Linux MINT 19 distribution.